# Implement extension function Kotlin with couple functions from class

Tags: kotlin

I have a problem with understanding how to implement extension function, which calls other functions inside the class. My goal is to implement extension function that calls in this case  `open()`, `find()` and `close()`.

`Fridge` class is as follows:

```
class Fridge {
    fun open() = println(1)
    fun find(productName: String): Product {
        println(productName)
        return 4
    }

    fun close() = println(3)
}
```

I have no problem with writing single extension function lets say:

`fun Double.addInt(i: Int) = this + i.toDouble()`

But I'm confused with multiple funcions at once, also specified return type gets me confused. What I have is:

```
fun Fridge.take(productName: String): Product {
    open()
    find(productName)
    close()
    //return this.find(productName)
}
```

Where have i made a mistake? Right now I guess it's return type, but how to return `Product`?

(This is a task from `hyperskill` )

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The traditional answer is to store the result in a temporary variable, so you can return it later:

```
fun Fridge.take(productName: String): Product {
    open()
    val result = find(productName)
    close()
    return result
}
```

Kotlin also provides a shorter alternative that you may find more or less clear:

```
fun Fridge.take(productName: String): Product {
    open()
    return find(productName)
           .also{ close() }
}
```

This uses the [`also()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) scope function, which simply returns the object it was called on (in this case, the Product we want to return).  (I've used this for simple cases, such as logging; but I think it could be confusing for anything more complicated.)

LATER UPDATE:

I missed a big safety issue with the code above: what happens if there's a problem finding the product, and `find()` throws an exception?  It will exit the method immediately, leaving the fridge open!

That's usually a bad idea.  In the case of a fridge, it could lead to your food getting warm; in other programs, leaving a resource open could prevent it being used again.  The usual way to address this is with a `try`…`finally` block — which, coincidentally, gives another answer to the original problem:

```
fun Fridge.take(productName: String): Product {
    open()
    try {
        return find(productName)
    } finally {
        close()
    }
}
```

This will open the fridge, and try to find and return the product.  But, whatever happens, if the fridge was opened, this will *always* close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `this` keyword here as follows:

```
fun Fridge.take(productName: String): Product {
    this.open()
    val prod = this.find(productName)
    this.close()
    return prod  

}
```